# Using Two sample tests instead of one sample tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

Can two-sample tests (such as the Kuiper two-sample test) be used instead of one sample test?
I mean, if we want to check the goodness of fit of our distribution in comparison to a normal distribution, we should usually use one sample test. However, we can also create a normal distribution with the same mean and variance of our main data and then compare this new data with our main data using a two-sample test to see whether our main data fits normal distribution or not.
Are there any problems with this procedure?

Comment: How do you get a second sample?

Comment: @Dave: I create a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation and same size of the main data using tools such as "normrnd" command of matab.

Comment: Do you mean that you *generate a random sample from a normal distribution*? A sample is not a distribution.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems with this approach.

The first is that you're throwing away information -- you know a thing that you're replacing with a noisy approximation. This costs you in power - you are less likely to reject a false null for a given significance level.

The second is that two people with the same data (and hence the same information about the null) will sometimes come to different conclusions at the same significance level (by generating different random samples). This is an undesirable property in general.

A third (closely related) issue is that, given your particular randomly generated sample, you're impacted by the specific "details" of your randomly generated sample (the particular characteristics of its deviations from the population distribution).

For example:

(i) Imagine that your new sample is (by chance) a little right skew when then original sample was also right skew. Then you're less able to detect that right skew than you could be.

(ii) On the other hand, imagine that the original sample was in fact drawn from a normal distribution but the sample is a little right skew (by chance). Now imagine your generated sample is a little left skew. You're now more likely to reject the null than you would be with a one-sample test -- you're spotting a phantom "too much right skewness" in the sample that a one-sample test would be less likely to "find" than you are with this particular generated sample.

---

There are some situations where it can make sense to use a two sample test statistic to do a one sample test -- but they don't involve randomly generating the second sample. Rather, the second sample will be derived from the first in some fashion (related to the hypothesis). The null distribution of the test statistic might not necessarily have its usual form (if that dependence impacts the type I error rate).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Glen_b. What if I create the new data using the CDF of normal distribution and at exactly the same points as the main data? Can I then use a two-sample test to check the normality?

Comment: Oh, I meant to come back and add to that answer. It occurs to me you're trying to test general normality (unspecified mean and sd) with a test for a completely specified distribution. This is already a problem for either one or two sample tests; you need different tables. I'm not sure I follow your exact intent with "create the new data using the CDF of normal distribution and at exactly the same points as the main data". It may be that there's something that could be done -- but again, tables will change. What is leading you to want to use a two-sample test to test a one-sample hypothesis?